# I have error in inner join statement

Tags: vb.net

I have an error in an inner join statement. I have 2 tables, input and input1.
In input field, I have the material id name
input1 I have another details on material.
When I use inner join, I have lerrorinfo.getdescription failed whith e_fail(0x80004005)

My code:

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM input1 inner join input on input1.id = input.id where [input.id] = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'", conn)
dt.Clear()
da.Fill(dt)
da.Dispose()
da = Nothing
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "اسم المادة"
DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "الكمية"
DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "رقم المستند"
DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderText = "تاريخ المستند"
DataGridView1.Columns(4).HeaderText = "المستلم"
DataGridView1.Columns(5).HeaderText = "المسلم"
DataGridView1.Columns(6).HeaderText = "تاريخ التسليم"
DataGridView1.Columns(7).HeaderText = "رقم الموافقه "
DataGridView1.Columns(8).HeaderText = "تاريخ الموافقه"
DataGridView1.Columns(9).HeaderText = "ملاحظات الموافقه"
DataGridView1.Columns(10).HeaderText = "تاريخ الموافقه"
DataGridView1.Columns(11).HeaderText = "الملاحظات"
```

Comment: please i need answer all my system independent on this code

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I've written OleDB Sql (Access, etc.), but I'll take a stab at it.  You don't have your connection string here, so not sure of the version/brand of database.  I like to keep things simple so as not to run afoul of database idiosyncrasies, so here goes:

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT specificfield1, specificfield2 FROM input1, input where input1.id = input.id and [input.id] = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'", conn)
```

I don't know what the structure of your two data tables are and you are using "Select *", if the tables are not identical , that may generate an error or (very) unexpected results.  Also, I like to be very specific as to what data I return and how the tables are linked.  I have found that what works with one database doesn't necessarily work with another.  So if you want data from both tables, alias the tables and be specific about what columns you want in the resultset from what table.  That's what I do anyway.  See if this example doesn't work for you.

R/
Prescott ...

Comment: dir sir Prescott Chartier i use to table (input1) and (input) the fields in input1 is id,amount,dat_in,provider,notesinpu    and the fields in input is id,kind

Comment: can i have your Facebook to send you my project . the same error shown in da.fill(dt)        IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

Comment: Zip it up and send it to the email address in my profile.  Also, send me the create scripts for the two tables you use so I'll have the exact same tables.  What version of Oracle are you using?  I have 11g.

Comment: i use access database and i will send my project to you i use vb.net 2012